# Entities not getting added

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Take the following EF based code:

```
var newItem = context.Items.CreateObject();
newItem.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
newItem.Name = "Some text";
context.Items.AddObject(newItem);
int count = context.Items.Count();
```

What would cause the count to return zero in this circumstance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

It should look like this

```
var newItem = context.Items.CreateObject();
newItem.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
newItem.Name = "Some text";
context.Items.AddObject(newItem);
context.SaveChanges();   
int count = context.Items.Count();
```

Answer (score 5):

@John is right. I'm just adding why? You didn't call `SaveChanges` before calling `Count`. `Count` is extension method from `IQueryable` and it makes query to the database and return count of stored entities. Unit you call `SaveChanges` the entity is not stored.

If you want number of pending inserts you can call:

```
var count = context.ObjectStateManager
                   .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                   .Select(e => e.Entity)
                   .OfType<Item>()
                   .Count();
```

Comment: John's question was correct within the context of my question, however, your solution ended up being the one I used.